# mysqli conversion fetch query

Tags: php, mysqli

How can i convert this statement into mysqli. i tried converting it but is not working. what am i missing. I want to connect to a login form.

This is the code i converted.

```
<?php
include('admin/dbcon.php');
        session_start();
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        /* teacher */
        $query_teacher = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'")or die(mysql_error());
        $num_row_teacher = mysql_num_rows($query_teacher);
        $row_teahcer = mysql_fetch_array($query_teacher);

        /* admin */
        $query_admin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'")or die(mysql_error());
        $num_row_admin = mysql_num_rows($query_admin);
        $row_admin = mysql_fetch_array($query_admin);


         if ($num_row_teacher > 0){
        $_SESSION['id']=$row_teahcer['teacher_id'];
        echo 'true';

        }else if ($num_row_admin > 0){
        $_SESSION['id']=$row_admin['user_id'];
        echo 'true_admin';

         }else{ 
                echo 'false';
        }   

        ?>
```

This is the converted mysqli but i cannot still log on am i missing something. I will be very grateful if you can help me solve this.

```
<?php

// establishing the MySQLi connection



$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","retreat");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())

{

echo "MySQLi Connection was not established: " . mysqli_connect_error();

}

// checking the user
        session_start();

        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username'];
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password'];


        /* teacher */



        $query_teacher = "SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

        $num_row_teacher = mysqli_query($con,$query_teacher);

        $row_teahcer = mysqli_num_rows($num_row_teacher);

        /* admin */
        $query_admin = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";

        $num_row_admin = mysqli_query($con,$query_admin);
        $row_admin = mysqli_num_rows($num_row_admin);


         if ($row_teahcer > 0){
             //$_SESSION['user_email']=$email;
        $_SESSION['']=$row_teacher['teacher_id'];
        echo 'true';

        }else if ($num_row_admin > 0){
        $_SESSION['id']=$row_admin['user_id'];
        echo 'true_admin';

         }else{ 
                echo 'false';
        }   

        ?>
```

Comment: you are missing 
`$results=$num_row_teacher->fetch();
$results2=$num_row_admin->fetch();     `
after that set  `$_SESSION['id']=$results['user_id']`

Comment: @Shahmee It's procedural not OOP.

Comment: replace it with `$results= mysqli_fetch_array($num_row_teacher);
 $results2= mysqli_fetch_array($num_row_admin);`

Comment: @Shahmee `mysqli_fetch_array` will only bring back one result. If OP's table contains more than one user, you will need to use a while loop.

Comment: thanks so much. i have gotten the right clue. but the challenge is when i upload the file into my website i cannot add, edit or modify any data. but i can do all that in the localhost server. what might likely be the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
//db details
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = 'retreat';

//Connect and select the database
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}

            session_start();
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];



            /* teacher */
            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'")or die(mysqli_error());
            $num_row_teacher = mysqli_num_rows($query);
            $row_teahcer = mysqli_fetch_array($query);



            /* admin */
            $query_admin = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'")or die(mysqli_error());
            $num_row_admin = mysqli_num_rows($query_admin);
            $row_admin = mysqli_fetch_array($query_admin);


             if ($num_row_teacher > 0){
            $_SESSION['id']=$row_teahcer['teacher_id'];
            echo 'true';

            }else if ($num_row_admin > 0){
            $_SESSION['id']=$row_admin['user_id'];
            echo 'true_admin';

             }else{ 
                    echo 'false';
            }   


    enter code here
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing

```
$row_teahcer=mysqli_fetch_array($num_row_teacher);
$row_admin=mysqli_fetch_array( $num_row_admin);
```